# docker container cannot connect to localhost mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, meteor

A. I have a container that includes the following
       1. `NodeJS` version 8.11.4
       2. `Rocketchat` meteor app

B. This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:8.11.4
ADD . /app
RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN set -x \
  && cd /app/programs/server/ \
  && npm install \
  && npm cache clear --force
WORKDIR /app/
ENV PORT=3000 \
    ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

C. This command is executed well

```
docker build -t memo:1.0 .
```

When I try to run the container, it encounters the following error in containers log

```
{"log":"MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2019-01-24T21:56:42.222722362Z"}
```

So container can not be executed.
The `mongodb` is running and I've added 0.0.0.0 to `bindIp` in the `mongod.conf` file.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
```

My `mongodb` is installed in host(outside the container)
The problem was not resolved and my container status is Exited

I put the IP instead of the localhost,but it encounters the following error

```
{"log":"MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [192.168.0.198:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect EHOSTUNREACH
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that you're starting a docker container (a self contained environment) and then trying to reach `localhost:27017`. *However*, localhost **inside** your container is not the same localhost as **outside** your container (on your host). There are two approaches you could take from this point:

- Instead of attempting to connect to `localhost:27017`, connect to your host's ip (something like 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x)
- (Better option imo) dockerize your mongodb, then your services will be able to communicate with each other using docker dns. To do this, you would create a `docker-compose.yml` with one service being your app and the other being mongodb.

Comment: I tried to connect with my host's IP, but not working. this is my docker run..  
`docker run --name memo -p 3000:3000 --env MONGO_URL=mongodb://192.168.0.198:27017/rocketchat --env MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://192.168.0.198:27017/local -d memo:1.0
`

Comment: try adding `--net=host` to your run command

Answer (score 4):

- When you try with `MONGO_URL=mongodb://192.168.0.198:27017/rocketchat` add that IP to `bindIp` as well.
- With localhost `MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/rocketchat`

I also recommend enabling security authorization in mongo config. Then set a user and password for your database.

Keep in mind that any change to config file requires a mongo restart

Comment: After researching a lot I found this and this really works. Thanks!!